# Weird White Areas in Matplotlib Stacked Bar Graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a stacked bar graph using Matplotlib.   The graph seems to stack just fine, but there are these weird white spaces that appear when I display the result.  I'm thinking it's because I'm setting the "bottom=" plt.bar attribute to the current dataset, while from example code it looks like you're supposed to set "bottom=" to the sum of the previous datasets.  My endeavors to do this have yielded nothing but blank graphs, so I figured I might as well upload the code that shows the graphs with the unwanted whitespace.

Any ideas on a workaround for this problem?

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('D:/GIT/GSURFizDataProcessing/fizdata/fizmay2019data.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
#df.to_csv('D:/GIT/GSURFizDataProcessing/fizdata/fizproblemdata.csv')
df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
df = df.loc[:,[0,1,2]]
df.columns = ['date', 'sensor', 'value']
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df['Day of Week'] = df['date'].dt.weekday_name
weekdays = [ 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=weekdays, ordered=True)
df['Day of Week'] = df['Day of Week'].astype(cat_type)

motionSensors = ["D8MotionA", "D14MotionA",
                 "D14MotionB",
                 "D15AMotionA", "D15BMotionA", "D15MotionA","D15MotionB",
                 "D15MotionC","D18MotionA","D21AMotionA","D21MotionA",
                 "D4MotionA","D6MotionA","D22MotionA"]

df = df[df['sensor'].isin(motionSensors)]

df['TimeDelta'] = 0

listOfColors = {}
for i in motionSensors:
    listOfColors[i] = np.random.rand(3, )


usedLabels = []
for day in weekdays:
    datasets = []

    for sensor in motionSensors:
        print("NEW SENSOR ", sensor)


        parsedDf = df[(df['Day of Week']==day) & (df['sensor']==sensor)]



        firstValue = parsedDf["value"].iloc[0]
        if firstValue == "OFF":
            parsedDf.drop(parsedDf.head(1).index, inplace=True)

        # Get seconds
        parsedDf['TimeDelta'] = parsedDf['date'].shift(-1) - parsedDf['date']
        parsedDf.iloc[::2]
        parsedDf = parsedDf[parsedDf['TimeDelta'] < timedelta(days=2)]

        parsedDf.drop(parsedDf.tail(1).index, inplace=True)

        parsedDf["TimeDelta"] / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
        summed = parsedDf["TimeDelta"].sum()
        summed = summed.total_seconds()
        summed = summed / 3600

        #labelText = sensor + ": " + ("%.2f" % sum) + " hrs"
        #print(labelText)

        if sensor in usedLabels:
            plt.bar(day, summed, 0.4, color=listOfColors[sensor], bottom=summed)
        else:
            plt.bar(day, summed, 0.4, color=listOfColors[sensor], label=sensor, bottom=summed)
            usedLabels.append(sensor)

        datasets.append(summed)

plt.title("Fiz May 2019 Usage Data")
plt.ylabel("Time Spent (hr)")
ax = plt.subplot(111)
chartBox = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([chartBox.x0, chartBox.y0, chartBox.width*0.6, chartBox.height])
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.45, 0.8), shadow=True, ncol=1)
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.45, 0.8))
plt.show()
```

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the bars were overlapping: They weren't even stacking to begin with.